# Late binding on CreateProcess with C# returns null value

Tags: c#, createprocess, late-binding, kernel32, argumentnullexception

I'm trying to use late binding on CreateProcess function in kernel32.dll, however, it returns a null value unlike any other function.

Here's the code I'm using for the late binding

```
public abstract class LateBinding
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping = false, SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
    private static extern LBHandle LoadLibrary(string fileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(LBHandle hModule, string procname);

    private Delegate Result = default(Delegate);

    public Delegate Call(string library, string method, Type type)
    {
        LBHandle Lib = LoadLibrary(library);
        if (!Lib.IsInvalid && !Lib.IsClosed)
        {
            Result = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(GetProcAddress(Lib, method), type);                
            Lib.Close();
        }
        return Result;
    }
}

[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
public sealed class LBHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    private LBHandle() : base(true) { }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return FreeLibrary(handle);
    }
}
```

and this how I invoke the function

```
private delegate bool dCreateProcess(string applicationName, string commandLine, IntPtr processAttributes, IntPtr threadAttributes, bool inheritHandles, uint creationFlags, IntPtr environment, string currentDirectory, ref STARTUP_INFORMATION startupInfo, ref PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation);
dCreateProcess CreateProcess = Call("kernel32.dll", "CreateProcess", typeof(dCreateProcess)) as dCreateProcess;
```

Comment: `LoadLibrary` returns an `IntPtr` that is a handle to the module, not sure how you are unwrapping it into that class or if it works that way.  Have you tried seeing what the last error is after running it?  You have set last error to true so you should be able to inspect it.

Comment: Check this out: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/06/typesafe-getprocaddress.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function named `CreateProcess` in kernel32.  It exists in two versions `CreateProcessA` (ANSI) and `CreateProcessW` (Unicode).  You can see that at the button the [documentation for CreateProcess on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

This is not unique to `CreateProcess` almost every Win32 API function that takes a string will have an `A` and a `W` version.

The following is what you want:

```
dCreateProcess CreateProcess = Call("kernel32.dll", "CreateProcessW", typeof(dCreateProcess)) as dCreateProcess;
```

See also [What is the difference between CreateProcess and CreateProcessA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060991/what-is-the-difference-between-createprocess-and-createprocessa)

Comment: You also should not call `FreeLibrary` until you are done calling the function.  `FreeLibrary` will unload the DLL from your process.  You don't see the problem with kernel32, since it was already loaded but if you call a user Dll function after calling `FreeLibrary` you will crash.

Comment: It appears that was the problem all along, thank you for clarifying this to me.

Answer (score 1):

`kernel32.dll` does not actually export a function entry point with the name `CreateProcess` - it's either `CreateProcessA` or in your case `CreateProcessW` for unicode (Wide) arguments.